# Leaflet : LayerGroup of Popups can't have modified width / height

Tags: angular, leaflet

My aim is to add additionnal popups for each `Marker` already defined in another `LayerGroup`. These `Popups` should then be controlled through a Leaflet `LayerControl`, displaying / hiding all the additionnal popups at the same time.

[image]

As you can see in the linked image, it works great. My issue is that I now want to **reduce** the size of these popups, because they are quite big for the little information they contain.

Here is my attempt using the function adding the Popups to another `LayerGroup`, and using the Leaflet `PopupOptions` : `maxWidth` and `maxHeight`, but it doesn't work at all.

I noticed that **it works as intended if I add the new Popups to the map directly**, but **I need to be able to control the `LayerGroup` from the `LayerControl`**. Do I have to use hacks through CSS to achieve my goal ? Isn't there a simple solution with my existing code ?

**layers.conf.ts**

```
  const markers: L.Marker[] = GlobalMapService.jsonToArray(globalMapService.markersLayer.getLayers());
  const labelsLayer = L.layerGroup(null); // LayerGroup containing my Popups

  markers.forEach((marker, index) => {
    L.popup({
      offset: [2, -25],   // This works (needed for Angular integration).
      closeButton: false, // This works (as you can see).
      maxWidth: 30,       // This doesn't work at all with a LayerGroup.
      maxHeight: 25       // Same as above.
    })
      .setLatLng(marker.getLatLng())
      .setContent('ID : ' + (index + 1))
      .addTo(labelsLayer);
  });

  return labelsLayer;
```

**layers.conf.ts**

```
  const overlays: L.Control.LayersObject = {
    'Labels': labelsLayer
  };
  globalMapService.overlays = overlays;
```

**LeafletMapComponent.ts**

```
  const map = L.map(this.mapEl.nativeElement, {
    center: [51.505, -0.09],
    zoom: 7,
    layers: [
      this.leafletService.baseLayers['Standard'], // BaseLayer
    ]
  });

  L.control.layers(this.leafletService.baseLayers, this.globalMapService.overlays)
  .addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is add a custom css class to your popup :

```
markers.forEach((marker, index) => {
    L.popup({
        className: 'small-popup',
        offset: [2, -25],
        closeButton: false
    })
    .setLatLng(marker.getLatLng())
    .setContent('<div class="popup">ID : ' + (index + 1) + '</div>')
    .addTo(labelsLayer);
});
```

I've added a `div` inside your popup, you don't need it but you can have also more control `inside` your popup.

Then add this css :

```
.small-popup {
    max-width: 30px;
    max-height: 25px;
}
```

This is what I've done and for me it's a great solution since you can easily edit your css afterward.

Comment: Sorry for making you feel sad ... You really haven't got any error in your console ?